# How to convert `List<Student>` to `List<string>`?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I got an error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List'StudentsBirthdays.Core.Domain.Student' to System.Collections.Generic.List'string'. How can i solve it?

```
public List<string> GetThreeOldestStudents()
{
    List<string> studOld = new List<string>();
    studOld = db.Students.OrderBy(b => b.Birthday).Take(3).ToList();
    return studOld;
}
```

Comment: Well you're just ordering the students, taking the first 3 and returning those.. where do you expect the strings to come from? :)

Comment: You may select a string property from the result set before `ToList`. What is Students data structure?

Comment: @OlivierRogier  ID, FirstName, LastName, ClassID, Birthday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this. The Select function will let you transform your Student object into another type, such as a string, in any way you want. Below I have use x.Name, but substitute in a real property if that is not one.

```
public List<string> GetThreeOldestStudents()
{
    List<string> studOld;
    studOld = db.Students.OrderBy(b => b.Birthday).Take(3).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return studOld;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will replace the original list. So `= new List<string>();` is superfluous. Write `List<string> studOld = db.Students.OrderBy(b => b.Birthday).Take(3).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();` or directly return the value. `return db.Students.OrderBy(...`

Comment: Also, as a public method, it would be better to present an interface, rather than a concretion to the consumer. In other words, depending on your consumer's use case, you should choose a less-specific return type. I generally try to go the highest up the inheritance chain for widest flexibility, in this case `IEnumerable<string>` instead of  `List<string>`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you can do this. Regardless of what you pick, **you probably don't need a fully-realized list**. You can improve memory use and performance in your programs by staying with the simpler `IEnumerable<T>` type more often.

Option 1 — Stay with the full student object:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetThreeOldestStudents()
{
    return db.Students.OrderBy(s => s.Birthday).Take(3);
}
```

Option 2 — Just the names

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetThreeOldestStudents()
{
    return db.Students.OrderBy(s => s.Birthday).Take(3).Select(s => s.Name);
}
```

With either of these, if you *really* need a list (hint: most of the time you don't) you can always put the `ToList()` call *after* calling the method ( `var oldest = GetThreeOldestStudents().ToList();` ).